# How can I find the location of a point a certain distance between two others?

Tags: algorithm, math, point

Let's say I have two points on a Cartesian coordinate plane, `A` and `B`, whose `x` and `y` coordinates are double-precision `float`s. How do I find the location of a point `C` that is an arbitrary percent of the distance between them?

In other words, what goes in the following method instead of "`//Do magic to C`"? Remember that `A` and `B` each consist of two `double`s, which represent their respective `x` and `y` coordinates.

```
public static findProgressPoint(DoublePoint A, DoublePoint B, double position)
{
  if (position > 1 || position < 0) //Ensure that position is between 0 and 1, inclusive
    position = position - (int)position;
  DoublePoint C = new DoublePoint(0.0, 0.0);
  //Do magic to C
  return C;
}
```

Comment: Do you want point C to be *on the line* segment A-B, or do you want *any* point where dist(A,C) = R * dist(B,C)? That would be a hyperbole, IIRC.

Comment: **arbitrary percent**, are you sure? If that percentage is < .5, then there is no such point... and if it is > .5, there are two such unique points... and in that case I believe you need some trigonometry to figure out the exact points...

Comment: @wildplasser Actually, the locus of all such points is a circle.

Comment: The R in my formula was not intended as a radius, but as the ratio between the two distances.

Comment: @wildplasser I want it to be on line segment AB

Comment: @AsiriRathnayake yes, I'm sure. I want `0.1` to represent 10% of the way from A to B, `0.5` to be the midpoint, `0.9` to mean 90%, et cetera.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
double px = x1 + (x2-x1)*position;
double py = y1 + (y2-y1)*position;
DoublePoint C = new DoublePoint(px, py);
```

`px` is the `x` coordinate between `x1` and `x2` at the distance from `x1` proportional to the value of `position`; `py` is the corresponding `y` coordinate.

Answer (score 1):

```
DoublePoint C = new DoublePoint( position * (A.x + B.x), position * (A.y + B.y) );
```

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but does this really work for cases when `position` is not `0.5`? For example, it looks like the formula would return `DoublePoint(0, 0)` when `position` is zero, but it should return `DoublePoint(A.x, B.x)`. Same goes for `position` of `1`...

Comment: I tried this, at first... when `position` is `1.0`, it drastically overshoots. For instance, given `A=(2.0,3.0)` and `B=(4.0,5.0)`, this gives `C=(1.0*(2.0+4.0),1.0*(3.0+5.0))=(6.0,8.0)` instead of the intended `C=(4.0,5.0)`. Also, when `position` is `0.0`, it always returns `C=(0.0,0.0)` instead of the intended `C=(2.0,3.0)`.

Comment: if pos = 1 then a.x + b.x - a.x is exactly b.x

Comment: @ZdravkoDanev as true as that is, I don't see what that has to do with anything. Also worth noting, given `a.x + b.x - a.x`, any values for `a.x` are nullified.